# Why do I get the error "cannot borrow x as mutable more than once"?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a parser in Rust. I have to update the index for the lookahead, but when I call `self.get()` after `self.current()` I get an error:

```
cannot borrow *self as mutable more than once at a time
```

It's confusing since I'm new to Rust.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Token {
    Random(String),
    Undefined(String),
}

struct Point {
    token: Vec<Token>,
    look: usize,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn init(&mut self){
        while let Some(token) = self.current(){
            println!("{:?}", token); 
            let _ = self.get();
        }
    }

    pub fn current(&mut self) -> Option<&Token> {
        self.token.get(self.look)
    }

    pub fn get(&mut self) -> Option<&Token> {
        let v = self.token.get(self.look);
        self.look += 1;
        v
    }

}

fn main(){
    let token_list = vec![Token::Undefined("test".to_string()),
                     Token::Random("test".to_string())];

    let mut o = Point{ token: token_list, look: 0 };
    o.init();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Point::get` mutates the `Point` that it is called on. The function `Point::current` returns a reference to a part of the `Point` that it is called on. So, when you write

```
while let Some(token) = self.current() {
    println!("{:?}", token); 
    let _ = self.get();
}
```

`token` is a reference to something stored in `self`. Because mutating `self` might change or delete whatever `token` points to, the compiler prevents you from calling `self.get()` while the variable `token` is in scope.

Comment: what will be the right way to do something like this in rust?

Comment: @GOD restructure your code so that you aren't holding on to references to things which are being mutated

Answer (score 2):

@Adrian already gave the correct reason for why the compiler is giving the error message. If you bound the mutating expressions within a scope and then call `self.get` after the scope completion, you can compile the program.
The code can be modified as

```
loop{
    {
        let t = if let Some(token) = self.current(){
                    token
                }else{
                    break
                };
        println!("{:?}", t); 
    }
    let b = self.get();
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```