# Why does an immutable borrow in a loop last outside of its lexical scope?

Tags: rust

I am stuck on the borrow checker.

```
pub struct Gamepad {
    str: String,
}

pub enum Player {
    Human(Gamepad),
    Computer,
}

pub struct PlayerData {
    pub player: Player, /* actually this should be private */
}

struct Pong {
    players: Vec<PlayerData>,
}

fn update_game(_pong: &mut Pong) {}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut pong = Pong {
        players: vec![
            PlayerData {
                player: Player::Computer,
            },
            PlayerData {
                player: Player::Human(Gamepad {
                    str: "mydev".to_string(),
                }),
            },
        ],
    };

    game_loop(&mut pong);
}

fn game_loop(pong: &mut Pong) {
    let mut vec: Vec<&Gamepad> = Vec::new();
    {
        for playerdata in pong.players.iter() {
            match playerdata.player {
                Player::Human(ref gp) => {
                    if gp.str == "mydev" {
                        vec.push(gp); //omitting this line of code fixes borrow checker issues
                    }
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }
    update_game(pong);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=68324c93ab71143413c9f9a7aebffce8&version=stable)

This gives:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*pong` as mutable because `pong.players` is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:52:17
   |
41 |         for playerdata in pong.players.iter() {
   |                           ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
52 |     update_game(pong);
   |                 ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
53 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

While I *can* understand the error to some extent, but coming from a C and Java background, I really struggle to get out of this problem. I am mainly confused why the immutable borrow is not released after the for loop ends. How would you write this in idiomatic Rust?

Comment: In addition to what Shepmaster said, consider giving that mutable vector some thought: What would be the lifetime of the `&Gamepad` values in it? Also, does it make sense to have a `Rc<&Gamepad>`? The sections of the Rust book on ownership, borrowing and lifetimes might help you if you cannot answer these sub-questions.

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47618823/155423). If you agree, we can mark it as a duplicate. If you disagree, please further [edit] your question to show how they are different or to clarify your question towards which aspects you don't understand.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the intent here, but couldn't you make `Gamepad` derive `Clone`, change `vec` to `Vec<Gamepad>`, and `vec.push(gp.clone())`?

Comment: @NovaDenizen : you can assume Gamepad has certain fields which cannot be cloned.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I don't agree this is a duplicate. I am still struggling to see why the immutable borrow lasts so long that it prevents me to call update_game (which is outside of the lexical scope of the borrow above). I also tried updating the code with a Rc but that did not help either.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/84h7y2/help_immutable_borrow_lasts_longer_than_expected/?ref=share&ref_source=link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit poorly worded, but I see your problem.

The error says the immutable borrow occurs in the `for` loop, which isn't quite correct. Instead, it occurs on the line you marked: `vec.push(gp)`.

`gp` is an immutable reference to *an object contained within `pong.players`*. When you exit the loop, there is no immutable reference to `pong.players` *itself*, but there *is* a vector full of references to objects inside that vector.

```
pong.players : [ a,  b,  c,  d,  e]
                 ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
vec          : [&a, &b, &c, &d, &e]
```

Since you have outstanding immutable references to objects within `pong.players`, Rust has to consider `pong.players` as "implicitly" immutably borrowed, to ensure that none of its contents are mutated while there is still an immutable reference to that item. Since `pong.players` is a component of `pong` and is "implicitly" borrowed, `pong` itself has to be "implicitly" borrowed immutably as well.

In other words, the borrow of `pong` in `game_loop` lasts as such:

```
fn game_loop(pong: &mut Pong) {
    let mut vec: Vec<&Gamepad> = Vec::new();    // <+ `vec`'s lifetime begins here
    {                                           //  |
        for playerdata in pong.players.iter() { // <+ `pong.players.iter()` temporarily immutably borrows
                                                //  | `players` from `pong` for the iterator. `playerdata`
                                                //  | is a borrowed portion of `pong.players`.
                                                //  | As long as any `playerdata` exists, `pong.players`
                                                //  | is immutably borrowed by extension.
            match playerdata.player {           // <+ `playerdata.player` is a portion of `playerdata`.
                Player::Human(ref gp) => {      // <+ `gp` is a borrow of an element of `playerdata`.
                    if gp.str == "mydev" {      //  |
                        vec.push(gp);           // <! At this point, `gp` is added to `vec`.
                                                //  | Since `gp` is inside `vec`, the reference to `gp`
                                                //  | is not dropped *until `vec` is dropped.
                    }                           //  |
                }                               //  <- `gp`'s *lexical* lifetime ends here, but it may still
                                                //  | be inside `vec`. Any `gp` added to `vec` is still
                                                //  | considered borrowed.
                _ => {}                         //  |
            }                                   // <- `playerdata.player` is not longer lexically borrowed.
                                                //  | However, since `gp`, a portion of `playerdata.player`,
                                                //  | may still be borrowed, the compiler flags
                                                //  | `playerdata.player` as still borrowed.
        }                                       // <- `playerdata`'s borrow scope ends here, but since
                                                //  | `playerdata.player` may still be borrowed (due to the
                                                //  | fact that `vec` may contain references to elements of
                                                //  | playerdata.player), `playerdata` is still considered borrowed
    }                                           // <- the iterator over `pong.players` is dropped here. But since
                                                //  | `playerdata` might still be referenced in `vec`, `pong.players`
                                                //  | is still considered borrowed... and since `pong.players` is
                                                //  | implicitly borrowed, `pong` is implicitly borrowed.
    update_game(pong);                          // <! When you reach this line, `pong` is implicitly borrowed because
                                                //  | there are references to something 'inside' it. Since you can't
                                                //  | have an immutable borrow and a mutable borrow at the same time
                                                //  | (to ensure you can't change something at the same time another
                                                //  | part of the program views it), `update_game(pong)` cannot accept
                                                //  | a mutable reference to `pong`.
}                                               // <- At this point, `vec` is dropped, releasing all references to the
                                                //  | contents of `pong`. `pong` is also dropped here, because it is the
                                                //  | end of the function.
```

That explains the **why**. As for the **how** to solve it: Theoretically, the *easiest* solution would be to implement `Clone` on `Gamepad` (which can be easily done with `#[derive(Clone)]` if all of `Gamepad`'s fields implement `clone`; the standard implementation is basically creating a new object by calling `.clone` on all of the fields of the original) and then use `gp.clone()` rather than just `gp`.

This has a (probably negligible) impact on the memory use of your program, but moreover, it can be infeasible if `Gamepad` uses external-library types that do not implement `Clone` - you can't implement `Clone` on those external types, because you don't define `Clone` or `SomeExternalType` in your project.

If `impl Clone` isn't available to you, you may need to refactor your code; reconsider *why* you need certain mutable or immutable borrows, and remove them if they're unnecessary. If that fails, you might need to look into other types of pointers like `Cell`, which I'm not qualified to give information about!

If you don't need to keep `vec` around and do stuff with it after `update_game` is called, consider this solution:

```
fn game_loop(pong: &mut Pong) {
    {
        let mut vec: Vec<&Gamepad> = Vec::new(); // <+ Vec is created
        for playerdata in pong.players.iter() {  //  |
            match playerdata.player {            //  |
                Player::Human(ref gp) => {       //  |
                    if gp.str == "mydev" {       //  |
                        vec.push(gp);            //  |
                    }                            //  |
                }                                //  |
                _ => {}                          //  |
            }                                    //  |
        }                                        //  |
        for g_pad in vec {                       //  |
            // Do something with each gamepad    //  |
        }                                        //  |
    }                                            // <- `vec` is dropped
    // Since `vec` no longer exists, there are no more references
    // to the contents of `pong`, and `update_game` can be called.
    update_game(pong);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation !

Comment: @PaulPraet worth noting: Collecting into a `Vec`, and then doing something with each item in the `Vec`, is probably unnecessary to begin with. Unless you need to be able to reference all the Gamepads at once, you may be better of simply doing what you need to do in the body of the `for` loop itself. But, I don't know the specifics of your code, so do what you have to.