# Borrowing within pattern matching

Tags: rust, scope, reference, pattern-matching, borrow-checker

I'm writing a Rust program to collect the first words of each input line, which is somewhat similar to the Unix utility `cut`.

```
use std::io;


fn main() {
    let mut words = Vec::new();

    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
            std::result::Result::Ok(_) => {
                let words_line: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();
                match words_line.get(0) {
                    Some(&word) => {
                        words.push(word.clone());
                    },
                    _ => continue,
                }
            }
            std::result::Result::Err(_) => break
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", words);
}
```

This gives me

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling foo v0.1.0 (/home/ubuntu/projects/foo)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `input` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:37
   |
10 |         match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
11 |             std::result::Result::Ok(_) => {
12 |                 let words_line: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();
   |                                             ----- immutable borrow occurs here
...
24 |     println!("{:?}", words);
   |                      ----- immutable borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `foo`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I have read [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable) but am still confused: the mutable borrow happens on line 10 whereas the immutable one happens on line 12, so how could "a variable already borrowed as immutable was borrowed as mutable" happen? At least the error should be "a variable already borrowed as *mutable* (on line 10) was borrowed as *immutable* (on line 12)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)` returns an `io::Result<usize>`. Since the return value does not contain any lifetime linked to the reference you pass in, it does not create a borrow that lasts longer than that call expression, so it shouldn't conflict with the immutable borrow that occurs later. In fact the code compiles if you remove the `loop`.

The reason for this is that `word.clone()` doesn't actually do anything – it creates a copy of an `&str`, which is still an `&str`. Since this is stored in `words`, the `input` string is borrowed across loop iterations. Your code compiles if you replace `word.clone()` with `word.to_owned()`.

It's easy to clean up the code to avoid this problem. Here's an example implementation that also fixes the bug that `input` accumulates the data from all lines, which I don't think you intend:

```
while io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).is_ok() {
    if let Some(word) = input.split_whitespace().next() {
        words.push(word.to_owned());
    }
    input.clear();
}
```

Another alternative:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let mut words = vec![];
    for result in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        match result {
            Ok(line) => words.extend(line.split_whitespace().next().map(ToOwned::to_owned)),
            Err(_) => break,
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", words);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make `words` a `Vec<String>` (as of now, Rust tries to infer a `Vec<&str>` which gives lifetime problems, as the elements would refer to `input` which is changed upon the next `loop`-iteration.

```
use std::io;


fn main() {
    let mut words : Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
            std::result::Result::Ok(_) => {
                let words_line: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();
                match words_line.get(0) {
                    Some(&word) => {
                        words.push(word.to_string());
                    },
                    _ => continue,
                }
            }
            std::result::Result::Err(_) => break
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", words);
}
```

As a side note, `collect`ing into `words_line` seems unnecessary: You can simply call `next` (instead of `collect`) to find out if there is a first element.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, but why didn't `words.push(word.clone());` solve the "lifetime problems"? Since I'm creating new objects and pushing them into `words`, there shouldn't be a chance of any invalid reference :/

Comment: @nalzok Doesn't `word.clone` still point into `input`, which is altered in the next iteration (so that pointing into it is referring to stale data)?