# "Cannot borrow `*arr` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable" in a function call

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Please someone explain the code below and how can it be unsafe and why is borrowchecker complaining here? I am very new to rust and I come from a little bit of c/c++ background.

```
fn test(a: &mut [i32], place: usize) -> i32 {
    a[place] /= 2;
    return a[place];
}


fn main() {
    let mut values = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let b = test(&mut values, values.len() / 2); // compiler gives error on values.len()

}
```

Why does it work with first assigning a variable with `values.len()/2` and passing that to the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are trying to do two different things to `values` in two different argument positions and the current Rust implementation is not smart enough to determine that this use case is not problematic.

You can fix this by doing this instead:

```
fn test(a: &mut [i32], place: usize) -> i32 {
    a[place] /= 2;
    return a[place];
}
 
fn main() {
    let mut values = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let l = values.len() / 2;
    let b = test(&mut values, l);
}
```

Comment: two different things mean trying to pass mutable refrence and calling len function right? Thanks for the answer btw.
 Rust still has a long way to go if It can't handle these kind of things.

Comment: @ankit: Yes, the len function requires its own immutable borrow, and you also want to pass a mutable borrow.