# Rust mutating borrowed struct pattern

Tags: memory, rust

Here is an example of some structs:

```rust
enum VehicleType {
    Car,
    Motorcycle,
}

struct Vehicle {
    name: String,
    horsepowers: i32,
    vehicle_type: VehicleType,
}

struct Person<'a> {
    vehicle: &'a Vehicle,
    name: &'a str,
}
```

and in main function:

```rust
let mut car = Vehicle {
        name: "Nissan GTR".to_string(),
        horsepowers: 300,
        vehicle_type: VehicleType::Car,
    };

    let alice = Person {
        name: "Alice",
        vehicle: &car, // Share a reference to the same car
    };

    let bob = Person {
        name: "Bob",
        vehicle: &car, // Share a reference to the same car
    };

    println!("{} drives {}", alice.name, alice.vehicle.name);
    println!("{} drives {}", bob.name, bob.vehicle.name);
```

Now let's say we want to update the name of the car while preserving that Alice and Bob drive the same car

```rs
car.name = "Lamborghini".to_string();
car.horsepowers = 684;

println!("{} drives {}", alice.name, alice.vehicle.name);
println!("{} drives {}", bob.name, bob.vehicle.name);
```

This of course fails because `car` is borrowed by both Alice and Bob.

Why wouldn't rust compiler allow this? How does this introduce memory safety issues? How to go about a pattern like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable)

Comment: If you want to create a mutable object that more than one other object share references to, you'll want to use `Rc<RefCell<..>>` to wrap the shared object. For instance, make an object called `FamilyCar` that has a field in it for the car, which can be changed. `Person` can have a field like, `car: Rc<RefCell<FamilyCar>>`

Comment: You marked `alice` and `bob`  as immutable, yet you want to change them. This is exactly the kind of thing Rust aims to prevent.

Comment: @Todd No need for `Rc`, `&RefCell` will suffice.

Comment: The answer to "how doees this introduce a memory safety issue", is "this is probably fine, but shared mutability was proved to be hard to reason about in decades of engineering".

Comment: @ChayimFriedman to share the object between two other objects, I do believe you'll need Rc<>.

Comment: @Todd There is already a reference, so it can stay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mutate an object when it is immutably borrowed.
If you want to reference the same `Vehicle` object in the `Person` structs and be able to mutate it, you may want to use a reference to a `RefCell<T>`:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

enum VehicleType {
    Car,
    Motorcycle,
}

struct Vehicle {
    name: String,
    horsepowers: i32,
    vehicle_type: VehicleType,
}

struct Person<'a> {
    vehicle: &'a RefCell<Vehicle>,
    name: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let mut car = RefCell::new(Vehicle {
        name: "Nissan GTR".to_string(),
        horsepowers: 300,
        vehicle_type: VehicleType::Car,
    });

    let alice = Person {
        name: "Alice",
        vehicle: &car,
    };

    let bob = Person {
        name: "Bob",
        vehicle: &car,
    };

    println!("{} drives {}", alice.name, alice.vehicle.borrow().name);
    println!("{} drives {}", bob.name, bob.vehicle.borrow().name);

    car.borrow_mut().name = "Lamborghini".to_string();
    car.borrow_mut().horsepowers = 684;

    println!("{} drives {}", alice.name, alice.vehicle.borrow().name);
    println!("{} drives {}", bob.name, bob.vehicle.borrow().name);
}
```

NB: `i32` is a poor choice for the horsepower of the car, since a negative horsepower does not make any sense. Consider using `u32` instead.

Comment: Note that depending on the actual usage, `Rc` may be overkill. The example works with just plain `&RefCell` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d26ca6b15c2340b7a26c3c6bf42b7112))