# Immutable and mutable borrows in Rust

Tags: rust, scope, borrow-checker

I have a Rust application that I'm trying to develope. Being fairly new with Rust, I find the borrow-checker very difficult to work with. Below is a MRE that I isolated from my larger code base, but it exemplifies my exact problem. Inside `do_something` with the line commented in (marked with 2)), the program compiles fine and works as expected, but with the line commented out (marked with 1)) it fails with the error message further down.

I realise that the problem is due to memory saftey and that the compiler tries to ensure that nothing should unexpectedly change...however I cannot understand what the exact underlying difference is between line 1) and 2); as far as I can tell, they are identical.

I have also desperately been trying to find a way of resolving the problem in a generic way. I managed to solve a very similar problem earlier in the same code base with several `clone`s. In this case cloning v (which is the source of the problem I suspect?) doesn't solve the problem.

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct MyStruct {
    my_idx: usize,
    my_vals: Vec<String>,
    my_log: Vec<String>,
}
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self { Self::default() }

    // Push a message to the log-vector.
    pub fn push_msg(&mut self, msg: String) {
        let tmp = self.fmt_msg(msg);
        self.my_log.push(tmp);
    }

    // Format a message and return a String
    pub fn fmt_msg(&self, msg: String) -> String { format!("msg is: {}", msg) }

    // Get a value from my_vals. Create a log message, two ways.
    pub fn do_something(&mut self) -> String {
        let ret_val = match self.my_vals.get(self.my_idx) {
            Some(v) => {
                let msg = self.fmt_msg(format!("Some {}", v));
                self.push_msg(msg);        // 1) This line doesn't work
                // self.my_log.push(msg);  // 2) This line works
                format!("Some {:?}", v)
            },
            None => format!("None")
        };
        ret_val
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut ms = MyStruct::new();           // Init struct
    ms.my_vals.push(String::from("aa"));    // Push some value to the struct
    ms.push_msg(String::from("bcd"));       // Test push_msg-function, works as a stand-alone call
    ms.do_something();                      // Test function
    println!("Main, after: {:?}", ms);      // Just check the state of the struct after
}
```

Error message as below when using 1) in the MRE:

```
PS C:\Users\rust_stuff\borrow_test> cargo run
   Compiling borrow_test v0.1.0 (C:\Users\rust_stuff\borrow_test)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:24:17
   |
21 |         let ret_val = match self.my_vals.get(self.my_idx) {
   |                             ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
24 |                 self.push_msg(msg);        // 1) This line doesn't work
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
25 |                 // self.my_log.push(msg);  // 2) This line works
26 |                 format!("Some {:?}", v)
   |                                      - immutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `borrow_test` (bin "borrow_test") due to previous error
```

There are as always several very similar questions on Stack Overflow already, but I have not managed to convert those answers to my specific case. Among the other answers I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618823/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-immutable) to be most similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows that, starting from the `match` statement, the `v` reference obtained in `Some(v)` is still in use until the end of this `match` arm (to produce the return value), while the mutating operation `.push_msg()` borrows `self` **as a whole**.
But `v` refers to a part of `self` (something inside `self.my_vals`).

The borrow-checker forbids this situation because `.push_msg()` **could** mutate `self.my_vals` (even if it does not in the current implementation) and then invalidate the `v` reference pointing towards its content.
The borrow-checker relies on the **signature** of the called function, not its actual algorithm, because any change in this algorithm could break the calling code which was previously correct (according to the borrow-checking rules).

A workaround would be to prepare the result *before* the mutating operation `.push_msg()` so that the reference `v` is not used anymore after this mutation.

In your attempt, when you directly mutate `self.my_log`, the compiler can see that this reference does not overlap with `self.my_vals` referenced through `v` (`self` is not borrowed as a whole).

```rust
    pub fn do_something(&mut self) -> String {
        let ret_val = match self.my_vals.get(self.my_idx) {
            Some(v) => {
                let result = format!("Some {:?}", v);
                let msg = self.fmt_msg(format!("Some {}", v));
                self.push_msg(msg);
                result
            }
            None => format!("None"),
        };
        ret_val
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didnt realize that calling `push_msg` did "reserve" the _whole_ `self`. Although your solution of "cloning" `v` into the `result`-variable solves this problem nicely (I guess the `format!`-call essentially "clones" the object in a sense) I still wonder if there is a way of doing this without cloning?

Is it for example possible to tell the compiler that "hey, I only want _this_ variable to change, not the entire self" (e.g. guarantee that `func_abc` only touches field `xyz` of the struct, while `func_bcd` only touches field `yzx`)?

Comment: @pathoren Sorry, I don't understand well what you ask about "cloning". I didn't clone anything, I just moved the last statement of the `match` arm (in your code) three lines up. And about guaranteeing that a `&mut` function parameter will be able to only mutate a subset of the referenced data, unfortunately, I've never heard of that. Maybe [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) could help, by using only shared references as function parameters, but it depends on the meaning of your data.

Comment: @pathoren Ah, or maybe you consider `format!()` as cloning. Actually, I don't know why this call was made in the initial example. Anyway, this is not cloning since the new produced string contains something more than the original string. Maybe should you edit the question and add another example where you don't need this `format!()` operation, so that we can reconsider the impact on borrow checking.

Comment: Yes exactly, it was the `format!` I was thinking about, and "cloning" is perhaps not the best word here since it likely creates a new string as you point out. And as you also point out, my original problem did indeed have a `format!` there, so your solution _does_ solve my initial concern. However since this is the second time I encounter exactly the same problem I was trying to figure out if there is a more generic way of solving the problem. Perhaps a more general problem formulation would be "Calling f2(&mut self) from within f1(&mut self) where only one part of the struct changes."...cont

Comment: cont... After reading your suggestion with interior mutability, it kinda spontaneously feels like the way to go. I will try that and see if it works! Since your answer solves my initial question, I'll accept your answer. But if you have any further ideas on my more general case, I am happily continuing the discussion!